# Como executar uma função javascript no fechamento do browser?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e preciso executar uma função quando o cliente clicar no X do browser ou simplesmente fecha-lo.

Para ser mais especifico preciso executar uma chamada ajax nesse fechamento.

Existe alguma forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer saber como chamar esta função quando o a página for fechada (qual evento deve usar)? Ou quer saber como fazer a função que faça a chamada AJAX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é possível distinguir entre o usuário clicar no CLOSE do navegador, quando ele fecha a aba ou quando ele sai do seu site através de um link, mas, felizmente, é possível detectar quando um destes eventos acontecem, e é através dos eventos onunload e onbeforeunload.

- **onunload**: executado em concorrência com o fechamento do browser. Pode ser ruim em navegadores como o IE, pois algumas vezes ele simplesmente ignora o javascript que você quiser executar ao mesmo tempo.
- **onbeforeunload** (recomendado): executado antes do browser iniciar seu fechamento. É mais recomendado pois o seu JS pode ser executado antes, e evita alguns problemas com IE.

Recomendo o uso com jQuery, pois você já trata possíveis diferenças entre os browsers:

http://api.jquery.com/unload/